# Compress file with PHP make webpage is not avaiable

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, compression

Recently, my client website is collapsed in some certain page, not the whole website.
When open the C page (collapsed page for short) in Chrome, it will inform "The webpage is not available"

```
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED)
```

It looks like a problem with this option in my client's PHP file:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
```

When I removed it, the C page is back to work normally but the page is no longer compressed as before.
I tried to add it back with this code in some Google source at the end of page but now whole website collapsed so I can't put this option to PHP file now:

```
ob_end_clean();
ob_flush();
```

Is there any safe way to enable compression for website now?
I tried with .htaccess but it didn't work.

The site is using IIS server with Windows Server 2008.

Comment: You have tried with `.htaccess` and failed because IIS uses `web.config` which as a different structure to htaccess

Comment: yes,I think the problem is I follow a lot of instruction for Apache server and it didn't work for IIS server, please advise!